# Offset average calculation by rows/seconds in R

Tags: r, mean, offset

I have the following data set

```
Data <-structure(list(GPStime = structure(c(1581116832, 1581116833, 
1581116834, 1581116835, 1581116836, 1581116837, 1581116838, 1581116839, 
1581116840, 1581116841, 1581116842, 1581116843, 1581116844, 1581116845, 
1581116846, 1581116847, 1581116848, 1581116849, 1581116850, 1581116851, 
1581116852, 1581116853, 1581116854, 1581116855, 1581116856), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), MinimaxVel = c(3.091, 3.425, 4.617, 
4.277, 4.546, 5.396, 4.865, 4.802, 5.158, 4.381, 4.728, 5.394, 
4.346, 4.941, 5.191, 4.493, 5.189, 4.766, 4.671, 5.461, 4.321, 
4.985, 4.739, 4.537, 5.422), GarminVel = c(5.234, 5.207, 5.17358333333333, 
5.14013888888889, 5.10672222222222, 5.07327777777778, 5.03986111111111, 
5.00641666666667, 4.973, 4.861, 5.104, 5.076, 5.374, 4.871, 5.188, 
5.18627777777778, 5.18455555555556, 5.18280555555556, 5.18108333333333, 
5.17936111111111, 5.17763888888889, 5.17591666666667, 5.17419444444444, 
5.17244444444444, 5.17072222222222), VelDiff = c(-2.143, -1.782, 
-0.556583333333334, -0.863138888888889, -0.560722222222222, 0.322722222222223, 
-0.17486111111111, -0.204416666666667, 0.185, -0.48, -0.376, 
0.318000000000001, -1.028, 0.0700000000000003, 0.00300000000000011, 
-0.693277777777777, 0.00444444444444336, -0.416805555555556, 
-0.510083333333333, 0.28163888888889, -0.85663888888889, -0.190916666666666, 
-0.435194444444444, -0.635444444444444, 0.251277777777778)), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Where I would like to leave the column `MinimaxVel` as it is, but calculate the mean of `GarminVel` over different time periods. For example I have a `MinimaxVel` value and a corresponding `GarminVel` value. I need a new `GarminVel` value to to be calculated as `mean(GarminVel-1, GarminVel, GarminVel+1)`. i.e. the time period I am averaging over is 3 seconds, offset by 1 second. Below is the desired outcome for the first 3 sec.

```
 GPStime MinimaxVel GarminVel   VelDiff
1 2020-02-07 23:07:12      3.091        NA        NA
2 2020-02-07 23:07:13      3.425  5.204861 -1.779861
3 2020-02-07 23:07:14      4.617  5.173574 -0.556574
```

I would like to do this over different time periods, e.g. 3 - 15 seconds. I anyone able to help with the offsetting? I have looked at `lag` and `rollmean` but haven't achieved the results I would like yet

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rollmean` here :

```
transform(Data, GarminVel = zoo::rollmean(GarminVel, 3, fill = NA))

#              GPStime MinimaxVel GarminVel VelDiff
#1 2020-02-07 23:07:12       3.09        NA  -2.143
#2 2020-02-07 23:07:13       3.42      5.20  -1.782
#3 2020-02-07 23:07:14       4.62      5.17  -0.557
#4 2020-02-07 23:07:15       4.28      5.14  -0.863
#5 2020-02-07 23:07:16       4.55      5.11  -0.561
#6 2020-02-07 23:07:17       5.40      5.07   0.323
#...
```

In `rollmean` the default alignment is "center" which assigns the mean value to be in between two values. You can change it to either "left" or "right" based on the requirement.